# How to change edit mode shortcuts for Jupyter to use modifiers on Mac OSX

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to change edit mode shortcuts so they use modifiers. For example, I want to change the shortcut for "move cursor up" to `cmd+j` (I'm on OSX). But the problem is when I press `cmd`, it's not registering it as a keypress.

[image]